# Is there a git pull alternative to git branch/checkout's --track option?

Tags: git

Suppose there is a branch on remote called 'feature1'.

I want to work on it on my local machine. For this my tutor has advised me to use either the following commands:

```
git branch --track feature1 origin/feature1
git checkout --track origin/feature1
```

I know that if I delete the repo and clone again, then also it will fetch the feature1 branch. Is there any other alternative like maybe using some forced `git pull`?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Whether `git pull` supports any tracking option

Comment: git pull requires some kind of tracking to work. So it implicitly supports tracking. Beyond that I can only say that you've got the wrong end of the stick as what your asking for doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 1):

The `--track` stuff, while convenient, is a red herring. And to a Git beginner my advice would be that you should never say `git pull`; it is just a cover for ignorance.

To "download" the feature1 branch, say

```
git fetch origin
```

To "edit" the downloaded feature1 branch, say

```
git switch -c feature1 origin/feature1
```

Later when the time comes to push your new commits on feature1, say

```
git push origin feature1
```

Do you see? No need for tracking. There are fancy shortcuts and abbreviations for all that, true; but it is best to be simple, clear, and plain.